# appinstalled event is fired prematurely?

Tags: android, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've added an install button to my PWA in the handler for the `beforeinstallprompt` event and then use the event to prompt the user (as per [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners#trigger)) when they click it. I then listen for the `appinstalled` event so I can let the user know what to do next (close the browser window and open the app using the home screen icon - be great if this happened automatically as it does on iOS after adding a PWA to the home screen) and remove the install button from the app.

The problem is that `appinstalled` seems to fire prematurely, in Google Chrome on Android at least. I know this because if I look for the home screen icon after being notified that the app has been installed successfully I can't always find it. And if I then try to install the app again (using 'Add to Home Screen' from the Google Chrome menu) I get a message telling me that the app is still being added...

Have I misunderstood the `appinstalled` event? Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: From my own understanding, when the user selects Add from the browsers prompt, the appInstalled event is fired. But the device still needs to download and install the app which happens after the user has selected to add the app.

Comment: Ok. If this is true then the even is badly named. It should be 'appinstalling'. I have added a 20 second timeout after receiving this event, and even this is insufficient sometimes, and the icon is missing from the user's desktop.

Comment: Does anyone know where I would raise this issue? Perhaps the chromiumm project on github?

Comment: What is strange is that the system show a message indicating that the app is installed on main screen (so after the installation is completed). So there is certainly an event for that...

Comment: Notice also on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/appinstalled_event this event is indicated as "Deprecated"... :(